# Copy and Paste cells x times and change Cell address

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I need to copy cells *A1:C10*, and paste them X times. The X is in the cell D1, also in the cell A1 i have a formula

```
=IF('C:\Users\..\..\\E kompletuar\[data.xlsx]data'!$H$2=0;"")
```

I need the Cell row $H$**2** to change by the number of times the cells *A1:C10* is pasted. eg. $H$**3** (if i paste for first time), $H$**4** (if i paste for second time),$H$**5** (if i paste for third time) ...

Comment: Any code that you have tried?

Comment: no i dont have try nothing im searching in the net for that

Comment: This can be accomplished with a `For` loop. Otherwise, it's unclear what you're asking (specifically -- where are you pasting *to*?).

Comment: sorry i forgot to specify where i need to paste, i need to be pasted 3 rows after the C10 in same sheet it will be A13 , sow if i paste 4 times ne 5 will bi in the cell A52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after

```
Sub foo()
Dim x as Long, numberOfTimes as Long 'number of times to "copy"
Dim rngToCopy as Range
Dim rngToPaste as Range
Dim A1_FORMULA as String

'## Define the range you want to copy:
Set rngToCopy = Range("A1:C10")

'## Get the number "X" from cell D1:
numberOfTimes = Range("D1").Value

For x = 1 to numberOfTimes

    '## Define your base formula:
    A1_FORMULA = "=IF('C:\Users\..\..\\E kompletuar\[data.xlsx]data'!$H$" & CStr(2 + x) & "=0;"""")"

    '# Determine where to paste:
    Set rngToPaste  = rngToCopy.Offset(x*(rngToCopy.Rows.Count + 2))

    '# Copy and Paste
    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=rngToPaste

    '# Update the formula in the first copied cell/column A:
    rngToPaste.Cells(1,1).Formula = A1_FORMULA

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug it and figure out what is the `rngToPaste.Address` on the second iteration??

Comment: thank you very much it works except the number of times it pastes , it only paste one time not as the number in cell D1, also the formula changes but not as specified it change to random values

Comment: Nothing is "random" :) Debug it by stepping through the code. What is the value of `x` at the first iteration? Second iteration? Etc.  What is the value of `rngToPaste.Address` at each iteration?